# Autopan javascript on map

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I am having trouble with `pan` function. Its working but not as I want it to.

I have logo over map and would like to pan away from this logo so infowindow would be seen (auto pan left or right)..
Here is code:

```
if(locations[i][0] == 1){
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<div class="oblacek"><h4>'+locations[i][1]+'</h4>'+locations[i][2]+'</div>',
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][3], locations[i][4]),
        });
        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    }
```

A picture will explain it better:

[image]

Comment: So you want to slide the map to the side to see info popup? Maybe make your logo smaller then?

Comment: I want to slide info window left or right soo infowindow would be seen and also logo would be seen. I cant make logo smaller, it has to be that size.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is similar to what [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453329/google-maps-v3-like-pinterest-map-move-center-position-and-change-markers-area) and this [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473367/how-to-offset-the-center-of-a-google-maps-api-v3-in-pixels) discusses. As it states, with [panBy()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) you'll problaby achieve what you want.